# ¿Existe el concepto de "frase sustantivo" en español?

Tags: gramática

Muchas veces en [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) hablan de "frase sustantivo" , y que tal frase es una "frase sustantivo" y no una oración.

¿Existe este concepto en español?

Según ellos, "la bufanda roja que ella estaba ondeando" por ejemplo, sería una "frase sustantivo" y no una oración.

Comment: Si no me equivoco debería ser "frase sustantiv**a**", con -a, porque "frase" es femenino. O de otro modo habría que poner un guión al medio para indicar que es ambas cosas a la vez: "frase-sustantivo".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagino que te refieres a la expresión *noun phrase*, que en castellano es *frase nominal* (en Wikipedia aparece como *[sintagma nominal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintagma_nominal)*). El concepto no es específicamente japonés; no sé si todos los idiomas tengan un equivalente, pero todos los que conozco lo tienen. Una frase nominal es una palabra o conjunto de palabras que tiene aproximadamente la misma función que un sustantivo. Un sustantivo solo puede ser una frase nominal, como así también un sustantivo con un artículo, un conjunto artículo + sustantivo + adjetivo, etc. Dependiendo del idioma, se puede hacer que una frase nominal modifique a otra dando como resultando una frase nominal compuesta mayor.

Tu ejemplo, "la bufanda roja que ella estaba ondeando", es en efecto una frase nominal, ya que se puede usar en los mismos lugares de la oración que un sustantivo (más/menos artículo, etc.). No es una oración completa (del tipo sujeto + predicado) porque el verbo se encuentra dentro de una subordinada.

En japonés no existen los pronombres relativos que marcan las subordinadas pero en tu ejemplo esto facilita darse cuenta de que se trata de una frase nominal, porque la construcción termina en un sustantivo (mi japonés está oxidado pero sé con seguridad que la última palabra de esa frase será *bufanda*).

En los siguientes ejemplos puedes ver cómo las frases nominales (marcadas en negrita) pueden ser cada vez más detalladas según las modifiques.

> ***La bufanda*** voló en una ráfaga repentina.
>   ***La bufanda roja*** voló en una ráfaga repentina.
>   ***La bufanda roja que ella estaba ondeando*** voló en una ráfaga repentina.
>   ***La bufanda roja que ella estaba ondeando aquel día cuando la vimos pasar frente a casa a toda velocidad en su automóvil descapotable nuevo*** había sido adquirida en una tienda de París.

Y por supuesto las mismas frases nominales, que aquí son sujetos, pueden ser objetos directos de un verbo u objetos de preposiciones:

> *Vi pasar volando **la bufanda roja que ella estaba ondeando**.*
>   *Fuimos por la autopista con **la bufanda roja** ondeando al viento.*